# Server JObject has null value when used with internet explorer, Breeze.js

Tags: internet-explorer, breeze

I am using Breeze.js version 1.4.0 and metadata version  of 1.0.5 with Durandal.js to build SPA.
I have a method called saveChanges that returns SaveResult object. The method is configured as stated in breeze documentation. Here is the method that is used by breeze to save entity changes.

`[HttpPost]
 public SaveResult saveChanges(JObject moduleItems)
 {
   return _repository.SaveChanges(moduleItems);
 }`
When this is used with other browsers i.e chrome, Safari, firefox etc, everything works fine. But when I use internet explorer to run the application, my moduleItems as JObject always has null value. I try to imagine how IE deals with JSON object; Please, any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?  If below IE9 you will need to use a shim. See the Breeze docs for more.

Comment: I am using Window 8 OS with IE10, even with that, I still  referenced both es5-sham.min.js and es5-shim.min.js in order to solve this issue of incompatibility. But all seems not to workout.

Answer (score 0):

IF your using IE10 you shouldnt need to include the es5-shims to get it working.  Have you checked whether the browser is in compatibility mode
compatibility mode = ie7 -> doesnt work well
compatibility mode off = ie10 ->  works pretty well